# Regular expression matches to repeated part although I use a question mark

Tags: python, regex

I was needed to check if paths have correct names then I've created a regular expression as below:

```
^\/2\d{3}(\/2\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\/[a-z ]+(\/(g|o)(\/[a-z ]+(\/s)?)?)?)?)?$
```

And it works for correct names but unfortunately, it also matches the wrong one like the next: `/2020/2020-05/test/o/test`. The last `test` is invalid I must decline this path.

Examples of correct paths:

- `/2020/2020-05/test/o`
- `/2020/2020-05/test/o/s` (maximum, a nothing can be yet at the end)
- `/2020/2020-05/test`
- `/2020/2020-05`
- `/2020`

Examples of incorrect paths:

- `/2020/2020-05/test/o`
- `/2020/2020/2020-05/test/o/smth`
- `/2020/2020-05/test/test/o`
- `/2020/2020-05/test/o/o/smth`
- and so on

But as I know the question mark matches zero or one time so I cannot get what's wrong with my expression. Can anyone explain me, plz?

**P.S.** I use **Python** regular expressions if it's important.

Comment: What paths are correct and why? What is the problem? Why is `test` invalid? `(\/s)?` matches an optional  `/s`  substring, so it is not required, the `/2020/2020-05/test/o/test` just matches the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, each part can appear in path only zero or one time, after path must end.

Comment: This part `(\/[a-z ]+(\/s)?)?` makes it also match the last `/test`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes, only one is allowed

Comment: @Thefourthbird, yeah, it matches but I can't get why. I've added more samples of correct and incorrect paths

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/Xgal62/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you, seems it works perfectly. But can you explain me, plz, my mistake? Why does my variant not work? Sorry, I am weak in regular expressions

Comment: I just added a lookahead that disallows identical strings between slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you added the last but one optional group by mistake. You need to remove it:

```
^/2\d{3}(/2\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(/[a-z ]+(/[go](/s)?)?)?)?$
```

Or, using non-capturing groups for better performance:

```
^/2\d{3}(?:/2\d{3}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:/[a-z ]+(?:/[go](?:/s)?)?)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7R1tjj/1).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `/2` - a `/2` substring
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `(?:/2\d{3}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:/[a-z ]+(?:/[go](?:/s)?)?)?)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `/2\d{3}-` - `/2` and then any three digits
  - `(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])` - either `0` and then any non-zero digit or `1` followed with `0`, `1` or `2`
  - `(?:/[a-z ]+(?:/[go](?:/s)?)?)?` - an optional occurrence of

    - `/[a-z ]+` - `/` and then one or more spaces or lowercase ASCII letters
    - `(?:/[go](?:/s)?)?` - an optional occurrence of

      - `/[go]` - `/` and `g` or `o`
      - `(?:/s)?` -  - an optional occurrence of `/s`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tested better... Unfortunately, it still matches `/2020/2020-05/test/o/test`. Only `s` or the end of path can be after `o`.

Comment: @Шах [**It does not match**](https://regex101.com/r/Xgal62/2). Use the expression in the target environment. If you want to test it in the online regex tester against *several* paths that you actually use in a single multiline block of text, use `^(?!.*/([^/]+)/(?:.*/)?\1(?=/|$))/2\d{3}(/2\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(/[a-z ]+(/(g|o)(/[a-z ]+(/s)?)?)?)?)?$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xgal62/3). Make sure that you use `r"..."` to declare the regex in Python code (or, `"\1"` or `'\1'` will match the char with octal code 1, `\x01` char).

Comment: I didn't notice at the beginning, [it happens](https://regex101.com/r/Xgal62/4) if add space: `/2020/2020-05/test/o/test `.

Comment: @Шах `"tes "` != `"test"`

Comment: maybe due to my poor English, I can’t explain clearly... A nothing can be after `o` but `s` or the end of string.

Comment: @Шах Try `^/2\d{3}(/2\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(/[a-z ]+(/(g|o)(/s)?)?)?)?$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xgal62/5).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221159/discussion-between--and-wiktor-stribizew).